# Validating SSN,Email and Phone number in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

Could anyone help me on how to perform validation on SSN, Email, phone through a stored procedure in Postgresql?

Thanks.

Comment: Too broad of a question, but here is my answer if you want to focus on the Email component: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22671557/124486

Answer (score 2):

A stored procedure doesn't look like the right solution.  Use a domain with a check constraint using pattern matching.  There is an example on the [CREATE DOMAIN reference page](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createdomain.html).  For email address checking, consider http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Email_address_parsing.