# Postgres Function to Validate Email Address

Tags: postgresql

A check constraint which would call a function to validate email addresses is not working fine for me.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_IsValidEmail(text) returns BOOLEAN AS 
'select $1 ~ ''^[^@\s]+@[^@\s]+(\.[^@\s]+)+$'' as result
' LANGUAGE sql;



SELECT f_IsValidEmail('myemail@address.com');
```

The function is returning false, which should be true. I have tried a couple of other regexs but in vain. Can anyone point out what's wrong with this function?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpoSz.jpg)

Comment: And your problem is? I don't see any check constraint in your code

Comment: To be more specific, I have posted only the function which is not working.

Comment: And what exactly "is not working"? Do you get an error? How does the check constraint look like?

Comment: Forget about the check constraint. The function is not returning correct results. As you can see, SELECT "Policies"."f_IsValidEmail"('myemail@address.com'); returns false which should be true. :)

Comment: Your example returns true when I try it

Comment: It is returning "f" for false whatever I pass. I am using pgAdmin III on Windows 7. :-(

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Before you go putting a lot of effort into this, the thing you want to do is make sure you're not kicking out valid email addresses.  There's all kinds of insane rules for can or can't be in an email address, and if you get it wrong, in the wrong direction, a user with a perfectly valid email address might get rejected by your system.

The best way to determine if an email address is valid is to use it as part of a registration process where email is REQUIRED.  Anything else is a lot of work for little gain.

Comment: I disagree with this answer. Hard verification of an email address is the most comprehensive method of e-mail validation. It's also the least practical. What you want is a custom Postgres domain that doesn't exclude a single valid email address. Then you want to validate only the ones that pass that very low bar. This permits you to discard immediate trash, and request clarification from the user without ever bombarding your mail server with obvious junk. Demonstration: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22671557/124486

Comment: Meh. I see your point but I think you're far better off making sure you have some form of rate control in place to keep someone from flooding you with real OR fake addresses. After that whether or not you're throwing junk at the email server is not a big deal, because a few bad email addresses an hour just isn't worth getting all that worried about AND installing plperlu on my boxes.

Answer (score 22):

A bunch of these answers are *close* to the right way. These are the points for my submission.

- You want to use a domain -- **NOT the rule system.**
- You **do NOT want to validate these email addresses with a regex.** (Update Mar 2017: not really true anymore)

I show [two methods of how to do this the right on DBA.StackExchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/165923/2639). Both to check for the MX-record, and also using the HTML5 spec. Here is the short and sweet.

```
CREATE EXTENSION citext;
CREATE DOMAIN email AS citext
  CHECK ( value ~ '^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&''*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$' );

SELECT 'foobar@bar.com'::email;
SELECT CAST('foobar@bar.com' AS email);
```

For more information I *highly* suggest you [read the answer in full](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/165923/2639). In the answer, **I also show how you create a `DOMAIN` over `Email::Valid`**, and explain why I no longer use that method.

Comment: Remeber, to create functions on untrusted language you need to be postgresql superuser.

Comment: Thanks for this.  It does seem to allow "foo@bar" as a vaild email (i.e., does not check that there is at least one dot in the FQDN). Though, I suppose if s/bar/localhost, that would be okay in some circumstances.

Answer (score 5):

I recommend a solution using PL/Perl and the Email::Address module.  Something like the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION email_valid(email text) RETURNS bool
LANGUAGE plperlu
AS $$
use Email::Address;
my @addresses = Email::Address->parse($_[0]);
return scalar(@addresses) > 0 ? 1 : 0;
$$;
```

See also http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Email_address_parsing.

Comment: Do you know something about the performance of perl vs. plpgsql vs. sql functions? Given the requirement that just a regex should be matched against the value.

Comment: You can easily test that yourself using your particular data and the implementations that you chose.

Comment: Thank you for the help Peter, but I don't have perl. Can you guys find what's wrong in the function.

Answer (score 2):

If you can figure out a regular expression that matches email addresses to your satisfaction, consider whether it might not be more useful as a domain rather than a check constraint.

For some of the pitfalls see [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html).

Comment: Domain is a nicer idea to cook the cake!

Answer (score 2):

## Don't attempt to create a regex to validate e-mails!

It is notoriously difficult to accomplish.  Here's a better solution:

Assuming that you have Perl installed on your database host, install the Email::Valid module on the same host using CPAN:

```
you@localhost$ cpan Email::Valid
```

Then make sure that you have PL/Perl installed.  Connect to your database in psql and add plperlu as a language:

```
CREATE EXTENSION plperlu;
```

(Keep in mind that this is an untrusted language, so you'll be giving your db direct file access, which could pose a security risk if someone were to insert malicious code into your Perl modules or into the db functions.  However, you need to do it for the next step.)

Add the following function to your database:

```
CREATE FUNCTION validate_email() RETURNS trigger AS $$
  use Email::Valid;
  return if Email::Valid->address($_TD->{new}{email});
  elog(ERROR, "invalid email address $_TD->{new}{email} inserted into $_TD->{table_name}(email)");
  return "SKIP";
$$ LANGUAGE plperlu;
```

Add a trigger constraint to your table on your column (assuming that your table is named "users" and your column is named "email"):

```
CREATE TRIGGER users_valid_email_trig
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON users
  FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE validate_email();
```

And you're done!

This solution uses the Email::Valid Perl module to handle validation, which in turn relies on a regex to ensure RFC 822 compliance.  However, it is a monster of a regex, so don't try to come up with your own.

If you feel uncomfortable with enabling plperlu instead of plain plperl, you could probably port the relevant functions into your database.

Comment: This is not at all a good idea. Don't use triggers use a domain.

Comment: because that trigger will apply on every row update regardless of whether or not that field has been modified. And, also the meta-data on the type is absent. expanding that to another table requires you to maintain more triggers.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me:

```
psql (9.0.2)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "f_IsValidEmail"(text) returns BOOLEAN AS
postgres-> 'select $1 ~ ''^[^@\s]+@[^@\s]+(\.[^@\s]+)+$'' as result
postgres'> ' LANGUAGE sql;
CREATE FUNCTION
postgres=> commit;
COMMIT
postgres=> SELECT "f_IsValidEmail"('myemail@address.com');
 f_IsValidEmail
----------------
 t
(1 row)

postgres=>
```

Comment: This does not work for me. I am using the script on pgAdmin III on a new Query window.

Comment: Works for me in pgAdmin as well. Did you try psql?

Comment: I have uploaded a screenshot of pgAdmin new query. Could you please have a look and see if there's something wrong there?