# PostgreSQL regex to validate email addresses

Tags: regex, postgresql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION addUploader(INTEGER, TEXT, TEXT) RETURNS TEXT AS $$

DECLARE

  u_id ALIAS FOR $1 ;
  username ALIAS FOR $2;
  email ALIAS FOR $3; 

BEGIN 

  IF email NOT LIKE '^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+[.][A-Za-z]+$' THEN

    RAISE EXCEPTION 'Wrong E-mail format %', email
        USING HINT = 'Please check your E-mail format.';

  END IF ; 

  INSERT INTO uploader VALUES(u_id,username,email);

  IF NOT FOUND THEN
    RETURN 'Error';
  END IF;
  RETURN 'Successfully added' ; 

EXCEPTION WHEN unique_violation THEN
  RAISE NOTICE 'This ID already exists. Specify another one.' ; 
  RETURN 'Error' ; 

END ; $$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' ; 

SELECT addUploader(25,'test','steven@gmail.com');
```

This regex does not accept a correct email address. It should accept steven@gmail.com.It is also rejecting any other string.

stevengmailcom - rejected

Everything is being rejected.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Postgres Function to Validate Email Address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4908211/postgres-function-to-validate-email-address)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You don't use LIKE with regexes in PostgreSQL, you use the [`~`, `~*`, `!~`, and `!~*`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP) operators:

> `~`
>   Matches regular expression, case sensitive
>
> `~*`
>   Matches regular expression, case insensitive
>
> `!~`
>   Does not match regular expression, case sensitive
>
> `!~*`
>   Does not match regular expression, case insensitive

So your test should look more like this:

```
IF email !~ '^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+[.][A-Za-z]+$' THEN
```

You also might want to hunt down a better regex for email addresses, "a+b@c.com" is a valid email address but your regex doesn't like it.

Comment: Why don't you use LIKE with regexes but use ~? Can you please explain?

Comment: @ProgramerBeginner Because the [`LIKE` operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE) works with simpler pattern matching but the [`~` operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP) works with regexes.

Answer (score 6):

Validating email addresses is fraught with peril.  It's far easier to create a regex that refuses to accept valid email addresses than one that rejects invalid ones only.  Here's the [perl regex](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html) that's RFC822 compliant:

My advice is to accept anything, then use email to verify it works.  If you MUST do validation then use the perl module listed on that page and pl/perl.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want one of the [tilde operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-TABLE) instead of `like`.

`like` has a different syntax (for instance it uses `%` instead of `.*`) consisting only of wildcards, and they must match the entire string, so anchors like `^` and `$` can't be used with `like`.  I personally think of it more like file globbing than actual pattern matching.

Tilde operators give you a robust regex syntax more akin to egrep, sed, and awk.